# FetchError: request to url failed, reason ECONNREFUSED crashes server despite try catch being in place

Tags: javascript, express, error-handling, try-catch, fetch-api

#### The problem

```
FetchError: request to https://direct.faforever.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?per_page=10&_embed&_fields=content.rendered,categories&categories=638 failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED
```

I'm doing some API calls for a website using fetch. Usually there are no issues, when a request "fails" usually the catch error gets it and my website continues to run. However, when the server that hosts the API calls is down/off, my fetch API calls crash the website entirely (despite being on a try catch loop).

As far as I'm concerned, shouldnt the catch block "catch" the error and continue to the next call? Why does it crash everything?

#### My wanted solution

For the website to just move on to the next fetch call / just catch the error and try again when the function is called again (rather than crashing the entire website).

#### The code

Here is an example of my fetch API call (process.env.WP_URL is = https:direct.faforever.com )

```
async function getTournamentNews() {

  try {
    let response = await fetch(`${process.env.WP_URL}/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?per_page=10&_embed&_fields=content.rendered,categories&categories=638`);
    let data = await response.json();
    //Now we get a js array rather than a js object. Otherwise we can't sort it out.
    let dataObjectToArray = Object.values(data);
    let sortedData = dataObjectToArray.map(item => ({
      content: item.content.rendered,
      category: item.categories
    }));
    let clientNewsData = sortedData.filter(article => article.category[1] !== 284);
    return await clientNewsData;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return null;
  }
}
```

Here's the whole code (this whole thing is being called by express.js in line 246 (the extractor file).

Extractor / Fetch API Calls file
https://github.com/FAForever/website/blob/New-Frontend/scripts/extractor.js

Express.js file in line 246
[https://github.com/FAForever/website/blob/New-Frontend/express.js#:~:text=//%20Run%20scripts%20initially%20on%20startup](https://github.com/FAForever/website/blob/New-Frontend/express.js#:%7E:text=//%20Run%20scripts%20initially%20on%20startup)